# Gedit error : Failed to connect to Mir

Tags: gedit, mir

When I try to open gedit on my localhost using **sudo**, I am getting the following error. But I am able to open with out root(sudo).

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: Before "fixing" that please see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: Thanks for the help! You have indeed provided a great resource over this issue :)